# как сохранить полученный масив через экспорт node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Доброе время суток не могу получитщ масив запроса mysql в основной модуль node

Модуль db.js

```
let cnoect = (con) => {
con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");

});

}

module.exports.cnoect = cnoect(con)
 module.exports.query=(con.query("SELECT * FROM servis", function (err, 
result, fields) {
if (err) throw err;
return result
})
)
```

app.js

```
 const mysqlconectdb = require("./components/db/db");

mysqlconectdb.cnoect;
console.log(mysqlconectdb.query);
```

как сохранить масив в app